# Tracking malloc allocations/free with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, malloc, ld-preload

I'm collecting statistics on malloc's behavior when it allocates and free. Since each address for my system is 48bits, I can't 1-1 map that address to a static array(program doesn't load), so I use a hash function since malloc doesn't use the entire 48bit address range. But the problem is I still get hash collision sometimes with my multithreaded program.

What are some other ways I can track current malloc allocations?

Comment: There are an awful lot of pre-existing tools to accomplish this... `valgrind` for one.  I'm not sure this is a wheel you need to reinvent.

Comment: But any proper hash map container has to allow for the possibility of collisions.  If yours doesn't, you can fix it, or find some other implementation that does.